# Why IDEA taks a long time to importing / sync changes when I update a build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

IDEA. For most time, when I modify a **build.gradle** file. It takes a long time to importing or sync the changes. What does it doing? How can I see action details.

[image: idea sync]

Comment: Could you share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has to run the gradle build file to import its configuration. Sorry I don't remember what exact task it runs.

When Gradle runs any task, it first has a configuration stage where it reads through all of the build files and gets ready to run tasks.  For larger build files this can take quite some time.

To find out what is taking Gradle so long, check out the "Build Scans" section and other performance optimization tips here: https://guides.gradle.org/performance/